# ElasticSearch query, nested, Sense vs XmlHttpRequest2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query working in 'Sense' the chrome extension ( essentially just a CURL ) - However, when I run it through an XHR request ( angular's $http ) it returns me 'ALL' instead of the filtered results, and gives no errors. I've double and triple checked, my query is identical going over the wire. The below query works in Sense, but not as a query string with both GET or POST HTTPVerbs

```
POST product/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": { 
        "bool" : {
            "should" : {
                "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "or" : [
                            { "wildcard": { "brand.name":"*fapl*" } },
                            { "wildcard": { "brand.name":"*women*" } },
                            { "wildcard": { "category.name":"*fapl*" } },
                            { "wildcard": { "category.name":"*women*" } }
                        ]      
                    },
                    "boost" : 1,
                    "functions":[
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "wildcard": { 
                                    "brand.name":"*fapl*"
                                }
                            },
                            "weight":1.2
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "bool":{
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "wildcard": { 
                                                "category.name":"*fapl*"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "wildcard": { 
                                                "category.name":"*women*"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "weight":1.1
                        }
                    ],
                    "max_boost": 13,
                    "score_mode": "multiply",
                    "boost_mode": "multiply",
                    "min_score" : 0.5
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 100,
    "sort": [ "_score" ]
}
```

#### Composition of XHR2 Request ( Assume Angular 1.x && module $http ):

```
var params = {}, target = "product/_search"
params.size=100
params.from=0
params.query = { /*... that whole query mess here...*/ }
params.sort = [ "_score" ]
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: CONSTANTS.ELASTICSEARCH_HTTPS + target,
  skipAuthorization: true,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { Authorization: CONSTANTS.ELASTICSEARCH_AUTH },
  params: params
})
```

#### Any thoughts on why my result set would be different?? :

- Sense -

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 111,
      "max_score": 1.32,
      "hits": [
```

- XHR2 Request -

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3547,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
```

-- How a single result looks --

```
{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "staging",
    "_id": "208",
    "_score": 1.32,
    "_source": {
        "name": "Smoked Brown 122222",
        "images": [{
            "width": 1172,
            "height": 816,
            "imageUrl": "https://www.someurl.com1"
        }, {
            "width": 1172,
            "height": 816,
            "imageUrl": "https://cdn.*.*.com"
        }, {
            "width": 1172,
            "height": 816,
            "imageUrl": "https://cdn.*.*.com"
        }, {
            "width": 1172,
            "height": 816,
            "imageUrl": "https://cdn.*.*.com"
        }],
        "status": null,
        "description": "Some Description here",
        "url": null,
        "created_at": "2016-03-24T05:05:52.101Z",
        "id": 208,
        "bId": 7,
        "cId": 2,
        "band": {
            "name": "Some CO",
            "displayname": "some  hey",
            "id": 7
        },
        "category": {
            "name": "Women",
            "breadcrumb": "",
            "id": 2
        },
        "tags": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm inclined to believe it has something to do with `nested` elems... I need to show you what my DB looks like huh... 1 more edit coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post to Elasticsearch with an empty body its the same as if you GET that endpoint. So what I suspect happens here is that the actual query body is not being submitted. After looking at the `$http` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for Angular it seems that you're using `params` to pass the body of the query instead of using `data`, try switching `params` to `data` and see if that works for you.